# Free Map components For Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I need to create a country map, is there any free map component available in Flex?

Answer (score 2):

you could try interfacing with yahoo maps (http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/maps/) or Google maps (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/flash/tutorial-flex.html).

Comment: i need simple usa map with vector format all area need to be buttons.

Comment: As Shua mentioned, the degrafa library could be of some help. Right click and view source on this: http://www.degrafa.org/source/DegrafaMapSample/DegrafaMapDemo.html

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what type of maps you are looking for Degrafa has some real cool components.
http://code.google.com/p/degrafa/.

Out of the answers from bkildow I second google maps.  The yahoo renderer is slow as molasses.

Answer (score 1):

I've done a bit of work with the Google library and was impressed by its power and overall ease.

Some advantages are:

- Google keeps the maps reasonably up to date
- Most users are familiar with the way Google maps works as well as being comforted by the  look and feel
- It will do geocoding and road segments for you
- You can overlay your own polygons and points
- The Google groups (and the moderator Pam Fox) are very supportive

Cheers